# android emulator /proc/meminfo does not show the right value

Tags: android, linux, memory-management

I have an android application which enables some features only when the device has 512MB of RAM or more. This application reads the memtotal from /proc/meminfo (from Native C++ code) to determine the RAM size of the device.

I'm trying to install this application in an emulator running Android 4.1. I've set the RAM size of this emulator to 1024 and still the memtotal just shows **516312 KB**. I have tried to increase the RAM size to 1536 (1.5GB) and still memtotal value remains the same in the meminfo file. I understand some memory is reserved for Kernel and some predefined bits. But missing a whole GB of memory left me clueless. Below is my meminfo file.

```
MemTotal:         516312 kB
MemFree:          282584 kB
Buffers:            1056 kB
Cached:           105976 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:           141696 kB
Inactive:          75880 kB
Active(anon):     122328 kB
Inactive(anon):        0 kB 
Active(file):      19368 kB
Inactive(file):    75880 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:                 0 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        110560 kB
Mapped:            57468 kB
Slab:               5080 kB
SReclaimable:       1568 kB
SUnreclaim:         3512 kB
PageTables:         4132 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:      258156 kB
Committed_AS:    1898016 kB
VmallocTotal:     450560 kB
VmallocUsed:       20564 kB
VmallocChunk:     423940 kB
```